# Get sum of prices from from Eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a quicker way to do the following in eloquent, I tried withSum but couldn't implement it in my case

```
 $bCollection=B::where(['user_id' => $user])->get();
            foreach($bCollectionas $b){
                $total+=$b->b_by_a($condition)->first()['counter'];
            }
```

Comment: question is not clear. what are you trying to do? Are you calculating a sum of values inside a column or are you trying to count total number of records fetched from database?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.

If you want to get sum of some table which has relation, then you need to try something like this:

```php
$model->relation()->sum('column')
```

Comment: what's hard to understand I wrote a working query and I'm asking if there is an alternative in eloquent. I have x of B model I'm trying to get a number from the relation for each b and sum them